# Keras callbacks with train_on_batch?

Tags: tensorflow, callback, keras

Is there any way to use the keras callbacks when using train_on_batch?

I prefer not writing the fit loop from scratch. Any idea on how to use the callbacks mechanism?

Comment: Could you please describe more specifically what you expect from callbacks in `train_on_batch`, because the normal functionality that keras callbacks provide (doing something on batch/epoch/training start or end) does not make sense when your are training only on a single batch of data.

Comment: the questions would probably be how to include the tensorboard callback when using batches provided by the developer. At least that 's what I am running into right now and how I stumbled across this. So... how do you feed your tensorboard the needed data from keras training when using train_on_batch?

Comment: Here is one way to do it - https://gist.github.com/joelthchao/ef6caa586b647c3c032a4f84d52e3a11

Comment: may be some hints here - https://www.javacodemonk.com/creating-custom-keras-callbacks-in-python-3d4f6e9b